# Abbreviations and acronyms

Tags: acronyms, units

I need to make lists of acronyms, abbreviations and units. How do I do this in the easiest possible way? I tried looking into the glossaries package but it did not really seem like an easy solution to me as you need to read through several pages of documentation just to make it work... so what is the easiest way of creating these lists in latex?

Comment: Have you tried the [glossaries guide for beginners](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.html) which is much shorter than the main glossary user guide?

Comment: Yes I have. But it seems like printing glossaries requires perl unless you want to fiddle around a bit to make it work. Seems unnecessarily complicated to me.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the package `acro` or `acronym`.
An example: pag. 7 on `acronym` package:
[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\begin{document}
\section{Intro}
In the early nineties, \acs{GSM} was deployed in many European
countries. \ac{GSM} offered for the first time international
roaming for mobile subscribers. The \acs{GSM}'s use of \ac{TDMA} as
its communication standard was debated at length. And every now
and then there are big discussion whether \ac{CDMA} should have
been chosen over \ac{TDMA}.
     \section{Furthermore}
\acresetall
The reader could have forgotten all the nice acronyms, so we repeat the
meaning again.
     If you want to know more about \acf{GSM}, \acf{TDMA}, \acf{CDMA}
and other acronyms, just read a book about mobile communication. Just
to mention it: There is another \ac{UA}, just for testing purposes!
     \begin{figure}[h]
Figure
\caption{A float also admits references like \ac{GSM} or \acf{CDMA}.}
\end{figure}
     \subsection{Some chemistry and physics}
\label{Chem}
\ac{NAD+} is a major electron acceptor in the oxidation
of fuel molecules. The reactive part of \ac{NAD+} is its nictinamide
ring, a pyridine derivate.
     One mol consists of \acs{NA} atoms or molecules. There is a relation
between the constant of Boltzmann and the \acl{NA}:
\begin{equation}
k = R/\acs{NA}
\end{equation}
     \acl{lox}/\acl{lh2} (\acsu{lox}/\acsu{lh2})
     \subsection{Some testing fundamentals}
When testing \acp{IC}, one typically wants to identify functional
blocks to be tested separately. The latter are commonly indicated as
\acp{BUT}. To test a \ac{BUT} requires defining a testing strategy\dots
     \section{Acronyms}
     \begin{acronym}[TDMA]
\acro{CDMA}{Code Division Multiple Access}
\acro{GSM}{Global System for Mobile communication}
\acro{NA}[\ensuremath{N_{\mathrm A}}]
{Number of Avogadro\acroextra{ (see \S\ref{Chem})}}
\acro{NAD+}[NAD\textsuperscript{+}]{Nicotinamide Adenine Dinucleotide}
\acro{NUA}{Not Used Acronym}
\acro{TDMA}{Time Division Multiple Access}
\acro{UA}{Used Acronym}
\acro{lox}[\ensuremath{LOX}]{Liquid Oxygen}%
\acro{lh2}[\ensuremath{LH_2}]{Liquid Hydrogen}%
\acro{IC}{Integrated Circuit}%
\acro{BUT}{Block Under Test}%
\acrodefplural{BUT}{Blocks Under Test}%
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

This example shows only a few command. Units can be easily added with `acro` package:
pag. 10 on `acro` package:

```
\DeclareAcronym{ecu}{
    short = ECU ,
    long = Steuerger\"at ,
    foreign = Electronic Control Unit
}
\ac{ecu}\\
```

Steuergerät (Electronic Control Unit, ECU )

```
\ac{ecu}
```

ECU

Comment: This seems like it could work. Can it be used for abbreviations and units as well as for acronyms?

Comment: I edited the answer with the command to the unit

Comment: Thanks. However, I would prefer to have separate lists for units and acronyms. For example, I might like to have units such as W (watts) for power or J (joule) for energy in a list, but an abbreviation such as Inductive Power Transfer (IPT) in a separate lists. As I understand it everything will be mixed together in one acronym list when you do it this way?

Comment: You can classify any element (pag. 12 acro package) and than adding the list of acronyms exluding "unit" class and after the list of units exluding the other acronyms: add one list for acronyms excluding units with command \printacronyms[options], options can be exclude-classes = {list of classes (for example: unit)} and name = {name of the list}.